How to override __new__ and handle arguments
I am trying to override MyObject.__new__() in order to verify that it has been called by the MyObject.create() method before creating the instance and returning it and raise an error if it is not. I have to make a separate create() method because it have to be async and we can't make __init__() async.
It works fine without arguments, but when i try to add an argument i get the error TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate). Don't i have to pass the arguments through __new__()? What i'm i doing wrong?
I thought this would be simple to fix but to my surprise hours of online search got me turning in circles.
class MyObject():

    def __new__(cls, myArg):
        stack = inspect.stack()[1]
        # If called by the create method of the MyObject class
        if stack[0].f_locals['cls'] == cls and stack[3] == "create":
            # Create object
            return super().__new__(cls, myArg=myArg)
        else:
            raise Exception("To create a new MyObject, use MyObject.create().")

    def __init__(self, myArg):
        self.myArg = myArg

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, myArg="test"):
        return cls(myArg=myArg)

I have seen multiple questions with answers about overriding __new__() but none of them take arguments.

The error is happening here: return super().__new__(cls, myArg=myArg). You don't need to pass the argument to the superclass.

You mean if i don't pass them they will still somehow make their way to __init__() internally?

Yes. See the example here

Internally, MyObject(args) is roughly equivalent to MyObject.__new__().__init__(args)

@Barmar __new__ gets passed the args too, no? MyObject.__new__(args).__init__(args)

Some important details:  __new__ only receives additional arguments if it is redefined, and the return value of __init__ ~~is not used~~ must be None. MyObject(args) is thus more closely equivalent to obj where obj = object.__new___(MyObject) if MyObject.__new__ is object.__new__ else MyObject.__new__(MyObject, args); if isinstance(obj, MyObject): obj.__init__(args)

Thanks to @Barmar for his comment. Turns out the solution is to accept the arguments in the overridden __new__() method without passing them as arguments to super().__new__(). They will magically make their way to the __init__() method through the internal working of Python.
class MyObject():

    def __new__(cls, myArg):
        stack = inspect.stack()[1]
        # If called by the create method of the MyObject class
        if stack[0].f_locals['cls'] == cls and stack[3] == "create":
            # Create object
            return super().__new__(cls)
        else:
            raise Exception("To create a new MyObject, use MyObject.create().")

    def __init__(self, myArg):
        self.myArg = myArg

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, myArg="test"):
        return cls(myArg=myArg)

obj = MyObject.create()
print(obj.myArg)  # -> test

As you see, the instance variable myArg has made its way to __init__() and is correctly stored in the instance object.

Whether you pass parameters to the super's __new__ depends on the object. You inherit from object and that type doesn't have new parameters. But others do. If you inherit from str, you'd want to pass the string you want to super's __new__.

Docs: Data model § object.__new__: "If __new__() is invoked during object construction and it returns an instance of cls, then the new instance's __init__() method will be invoked like __init__(self[, ...]), where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to the object constructor."
